# azure b2c google identity federation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am following the the url(http://www.rebeladmin.com/2019/02/step-step-guide-setup-federation-google-azure-ad-b2b/) to configure google identity provider.

First I have created a b2c tenant and switch to b2c tenant and tried to setup the identity for google. Somehow why i tried to login after setup and inviting user to tenant it is not redirecting to google.Can you please help me to understand where is the issue.

To create b2c  i followd this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfyHwD9sJJ4

THanks,
mbr

Answer (score 0):

You are following a wrong tutorial. Tutorial you follow is for [Azure AD B2B Collaboration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/what-is-b2b) (particularly [Google Federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/google-federation)), and not for [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview).

There is a guide specific on [B2C on how to enable Google Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-goog-app).